# How to pass a custom authentication form from within a view in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-forms, django-authentication

I'm trying to pass a custom authentication form I created to the auth.views.login.

All the tutorials I found do it through url() in urls.py, and with a url for the login view, for example:

```
url(r'^login/$', auth.views.login,{'authentication_form':MyAuthenticationForm})
```

But **I want the url to be the same as the index url**, if the user is authenticated then show the index otherwise show the login form with my custom authentication form.

Here's my **views.py** :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


def cp(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated():
      return render(request, 'index.html')

  # How to pass my custom authentication form ?
  return auth_views.login(request)
```

This is working, but how do I tell django my custom authentication form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you keep `/login/` as the login url, but use the [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required) decorator for your index view. When a new user visits your index url, they will be redirected to your login page, and then back to the index url once they have logged in.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def index(request):
   return render(request, 'index.html')
```

This approach is very typical in Django, and is simpler than handling the login with the index url. If you really want to call the login view from the index page, then you should use the same kwarg `authentication_form` that you have in your url pattern:

```
return auth_views.login(request, authentication_form=MyAuthenticationForm)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I'm new to django, but I'm noticing that sometimes when I make some changes it doesn't apply even if I restart the server.

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue so I can't help with that.

Comment: You don't need to. I'm just saying :)